# Windows theme ravaged after BSoD

Tags: windows, display, bsod

I know this is going to sound stupid, but due to a faulty RAM module, my Windows 7 x64 crashed with a blue screen, and after reboot, my theme was lost.
Sadly, I can't seem to figure out how to get it back: it seems to me that Aero is disabled, but switching to an Aero theme doesn't change the horrible appearance of my windowing system.

I tried to use the system restoration tool, but it failed - and now it seems that I don't have any valid restoration points either.

This is what my theme looks like:

[image: This is what my theme looks like.]

If anyone has a clue about what's going on with this computer, it'd be much appreciated.

Comment: Perhaps your graphics drivers got corrupted in the fail - perhaps re-install.

Comment: Re-install... what?

Comment: Re-install.. Windows of course.

Comment: Could you open an elevated Command Prompt and try running `sc start themes`?

Comment: @grawity The service is already running.

Comment: @Executifs: you've got a good command over the English language for someone whose os language is French! ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's either
  1. your video drivers got corrupted when you had the blue screen or
  2. Windows files related to displaying the aero style got corrupted.

First try reinstalling your video drivers, if that does not fix your problem, reinstall the operating system.

Comment: I'll do that then. I was hoping this could be solved through configuration. Thanks for your advice.

Answer (score 2):

Have you run the System File Checker (SFC.EXE)  This can assist in recovering corrupt files after a crash or other event This can often avoid a re-install of the OS.

Comment: The service can't be started :(

Comment: The Sytem File Checker is not a servcie but an application.  Do you mean you cannot run the program? It is located (usually) windows\system32